# How to append numpy x and y values into a text file

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code which creates an x variable (frames) and a y variable (pixel intensity) in an infinite loop until the program ends. I would like to append these values every loop into a txt.file so that I can later work with the data. The data comes out as numpy arrays.

Say for example after 5 loops(5 frames) I get these values

```
1 2 3 4 5 (x values) 
0 0 8 0 0 (y values)
```

I would like it to append these into a file every loop so I get after closing the program this:

```
1, 0
2, 0
3, 8
4, 0
5, 0
```

What would be the fastest way to implement this?

So far I have tried `np.savetxt('data.txt', x)` but this only saves the last value in the loop and doesn't add the data each loop. Is there a way to change this function or another function I could use that adds the data into the txt document.

Comment: sorry, I added what I tried. I think it is the right function to use but I am still not good at reading documentation to do what I would like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will zip the values into (x,y) coordinate form and put them into a list so it is easier to append them to a text file, in your program you won't need to do this since you will have generated the x and y already within the loop prior.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5] #(x values) 
y = [0, 0, 8, 0, 0] #(y values)

coordinate = list(zip(x,y))
print(coordinate)
```

So I used the Zip function, to store the sample results as (x_n, y_n) to a list for later.

Here is what I am appending to the text file with the below for loop (in the terminal display)

[image]

With in the loop itself you can use:

```
for element in coordinate: #you wouldn't need to write this since you are already in a loop
 file1 = open("file.txt","a") 
 file1.write(f"{element} \n") 
 file1.close()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: OP is asking about how to write data to a file in a certain format and not how to print them.

Comment: Just realized this, writing an answer to suggest with using the a in an open statement

Comment: Thank you, the Zip function was exactly what I was looking for and this puts the data directly into the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -- it is not complete because it will just append to the old file.  The other issue with this is that it will not actually write the file until you close it.  If you really need the file saved each time in the loop, then another solution is required.

```
import numpy as np

variable_to_ID_file = 3.
file_name_str = 'Foo_Var{0:.0f}.txt'.format(variable_to_ID_file)

# Need code here to delete old file if it is there
# with proper error checking, or write a blank file, then open it in append mode.

f_id = open(file_name_str, 'a')

for ii in range(4):
    # Pick the delimiter you desire.  I prefer tab  '/t'
    np.savetxt(f_id, np.column_stack((ii, 3*ii/4)), delimiter=', ', newline ='\n')

f_id.close()
```

If you do not need to write the file for each step in the loop, I recommend this option. It requires the Numpy arrays to be the same size.

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.arange(1,5,1)
array2 = np.zeros(array1.size)

variable_to_ID_file = 3.

file_name_str = 'Foo_Var{0:.0f}.txt'.format(variable_to_ID_file)
# Pick the delimiter you desire.  I prefer tab  '/t'
np.savetxt(file_name_str, np.column_stack((array1, array2)), delimiter=', ')
```